# No plugin found for prefix 'exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am new to Maven, I am trying to build an project using Maven 3.3 but I have encountered an following error using the command mvn clean install exec:java in command prompt.

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to mirrorId (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories): http://http=server.proxyserver.com
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.132 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-22T18:59:14+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository), mirrorId (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories)] -> [Help 1]
```

I have changed my proxy settings in my POM.xml and my POM is,

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                    <executableDependency>
                        <groupId>org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.zeppelin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
                    </executableDependency>
                    <mainClass>org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.zeppelin.Simulator</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.zeppelin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

and my settings.xml is,

```
<proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>http://http=xxx.proxyserver.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Thanks inadvance.. Looking forward to hear...Even last posted regarding is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you proxy configuration. Have a look at [this (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies)](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) or [this (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

The `<host>` should be the hostname without the protocol (which is already given by `<protocol>`. And I think "`http://http=`..." is a typo? Or what do you mean with the `=`?

You've written "I am new to Maven", do you realy want to use a proxy? If so you have to configure it correctly. If not just remove the `<proxies>` element from you `settings.xml`